# add empty item does not create value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I add an array of items in a select2 element, and the first item is empty.
I need the first element does have "value" attribute, but it does not have.

This is the array of items I add to the element:

```
items = [
    { id: "", text: "Choose element" },
    { id: 1, text: 1st element" },
    { id: 2, text: 2nd element" },
    { id: 3, text: 3rd element" }
]
```

I add elements with this code:

```
$element.html('').select2({
    data: items
});
```

This creates this html select:

```
<select>
    <option>Choose element</option>
    <option value="1">1st element</option>
    <option value="2">2nd element</option>
    <option value="3">3rd element</option>
</select>
```

As you can see the first element does not have "value" attribute, but I need it like this:

```
<option value="">Choose element</option>
```

**UPDATE**

It seems a select2 bug, corrected here:

https://github.com/select2/select2/commit/16b4840c0e2df0461998e3b464ee0a546173950d

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $element.html('').select2({
  placeholderOption: function() {
    return undefined; //This is the key
  },
  data: items
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/rLmztr2d/1668/

Reference: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2142#issuecomment-35820185